# Why is my method returning only partial details?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method that I made, called StopWatchWidget(). It is a timer and a Scaffold, complete with an AppBar and a Container. My problem is, when I try to call StopWatchWidget() from another screen, why am I only getting my timer and background? I do not get my AppBar or Container. Here is the StopWatchWidget() code:

```
class StopWatchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const StopWatchWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<StopWatchWidget> createState() => StopWatchWidgetState();
}

class StopWatchWidgetState extends State<StopWatchWidget> {
  final Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
  String stopWatchText = '00:00';
  void startStopWatch() {
    if (_stopwatch.isRunning) {
      _stopwatch.stop();
      // updateScramble();
    } else {
      stopWatchText = '00:00';
      _stopwatch
        ..reset()
        ..start();
    }

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (!_stopwatch.isRunning) {
          timer.cancel();
        }
        stopWatchText =
            '${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isPressed = false;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Trainer',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  actions: [
                    Center(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isPressed = !isPressed;
                            if (isPressed) {
                            } else {}
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const TwoTimerAlgsets(),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          '2x2',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text(
                          '3x3',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text(
                          '4x4',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                  title: const Text('Choose Algset:'),
                ),
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.add_circle_outline,
              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
            ),
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 60,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ParentWidget(),
            // child: Center(
            //   child: InkWell(
            //     onTap: () {},
            //     child: const Text(
            //       "F R U R' U' F'",
            //       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            //     ),
            //   ),
            // ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 665,
              child: TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                ),
                onPressed: startStopWatch,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 145.0),
                  child: Text(
                    stopWatchText,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now, here is what this StopWatchWidget looks like normally:

[image: What it should look like]

But, when I call it from a new screen, with this block of code:

```
     class Sune_CLL extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sune_CLL({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sune CLLs'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const OLL1ForTwoByTwo(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.white24,
              height: 125,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/SuneOrtega BR.png',
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 95.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sune-1',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const CLLS2(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.white24,
              height: 125,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/S2CLL BR.png',
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 95.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sune-2',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const CLLS3(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.white24,
              height: 125,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/S3CLL BR.png',
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 95.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sune-3',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const CLLS4(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.white24,
              height: 125,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/S4CLL BR.png',
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 95.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sune-4',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const CLLS5(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.white24,
              height: 125,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/S5CLL BR.png',
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 95.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sune-5',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const CLLS6(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.white24,
              height: 125,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/S6CLL BR.png',
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 95.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sune-6',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
        // backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const StopWatchWidget()),
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.timer,
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

All I get is this: [image: What I get; only part of the design showed above]

Any help is appreciated! I tried calling StopWatchWidgetState() instead, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the full code or the code of page you are coming from?

Comment: @s4nk37 Which code do you mean? I thought I added all the needed code.

Comment: Can you share the code of floating action button screen? As the rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: @s4nk37 I edited the post to include all of the code from the floating action button screen. Hope that helps. The floating action button part of it is at the very bottom.

Comment: Give me link of repo, let me run and debug it.

Comment: @s4nk37 I’m sorry, but what is a “repo”?

Comment: I mean Github Repository

Comment: @s4nk37 I do not have a GitHub repository of this project.